# How do I implement oauth in Kong when my mobile app has number and otp login?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, passwords, resources, kong

I want to implement Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant with Kong, but I have number and otp instead of username and password, what would be the grant type here?

Answer (score 0):

After a little research I found out that, if the only authentication is phone number and OTP, the same can be used as username and password in resource owner password credentials grant flow of oauth.